# Problem configuring gamemode on lutris [kubuntu 19.10]

Tags: kubuntu, games, 19.10

first i tried to install gamemode through Muon package manager and put Key: LD_PRELOAD
Value: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgamemodeauto.so.0 to lutris

i run `gamemoded -s` but before and after execution seemed to be inactive.  After a bit of research i decided to uninstall the package and install from command with both 32 and 64 lib to be sure but again nothing. Then i tried to uninstall and install again in case i did anything wrong and now i have an error :

```
GameMode ERROR: D-Bus error: Could not call method 'QueryStatus' on 'com.feralinteractive.GameMode': The name com.feralinteractive.GameMode was not provided by any .service files
ERROR: gamemode status request failed: D-Bus error: Could not call method 'QueryStatus' on 'com.feralinteractive.GameMode': The name com.feralinteractive.GameMode was not provided by any .service files
```

i went again to Muon reinstalled d-bus but the same error
I would really appreciate your help because i am relatively new to linux 
i also tried: https://forums.lutris.net/t/is-gamemode-disabled/6534/6

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this error was due to disabling the gamemode service just delete the package and the folder in home
then i followed this :

https://www.reddit.com/r/Lutris/comments/farvwt/how_to_get_feral_gamemode_to_work_with_lutris_on/

basically just

```
sudo apt install gamemode

sudo apt update
```

Reboot
In Lutris - Preferences / System options / Command prefix and type in ‘gamemoderun’ and click save.

Lutris will still show the toggle for Gamemode as greyed out though, but the command works.
to be sure run

```
gamemoded -s
```

before and after launching the game